# How to define optional json field using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have an object with one optional field and can not find proper annotation to model it. Any ideas what is the proper way to do it with Jackson?

Comment: All fields are optional by default. What problem are you seeing?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In Jackson you cannot make the difference between optional and non-optional fields. Just declare any field in your POJO. If a field is not present in your JSON structure then Jackson will not call the setter. You may keep track of whether a setter has been called with a flag in the POJO.

Answer (score 8):

Coming late to the party...

Using Jackson 2.8.6 via Spring HttpMessageConverter 4.3.6, I had to **change my setter** parameter to the unwrapped type, like so:

```java
class Foo {
    private Optional<Bar> bar;

    public void setBar(Bar bar) { // NOT Optional<Bar>, this gives me Optional.empty()
        this.bar = Optional.of(bar);
    }

    // getter doesn't need to be changed
}
```

Comment: Different optional.. ;D

Comment: I see it now :D

Comment: This is not the correct way to use Optional, it should be used as a method return type not for the type of member fields.

Answer (score 1):

We are using Spring boot 2.7.9 and Jackson 2.13.5.

In order to make a property optional when Jackson is binding the input json to our dto we use this in top of the dto class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
```

If we want jackson to ignore a property completely when serializing and deserializing, we use on top of the property, then it was not present in our json nor in the object when it was created from the json:

```
@JsonIgnore
```