# RestTemplate and variable number of variable

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-mvc

I have to post json to api_url for login.

```
{
"username":"testre","password":"password"
}
```

When I use postman to check this api, it reply successful authentication like below.

```
{
  "status": "success",
  "code": 200,
  "message": "username, password validated.",
  "data": [
    {
      "password": "password",
      "username": "testre"
    }
  ],
  "links": [
    {
      "rel": "self",
      "link": "http://localhost:2222/pizza-shefu/api/v1.0/customers/login/"
    },
    {
      "rel": "profile",
      "link": "http://localhost:2222/pizza-shefu/api/v1.0/customers/testre"
    }
  ]
}
```

For an unauthorized json like below.

```
{
  "status": "unauthorized",
  "code": 401,
  "errorMessage": "HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED",
  "description": "credentials provided are not authorized."
}
```

Previously I code to retrieve it using java. But now I want to refactor it using **RestTemplate** in spring. The problem is every example I read is written for fixed number of variables https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/. Here I get different numbers of variable according to the login success status. I am new to spring so I'm confused in creating the class for login reply which we get from rest template. (Such as this in the example `Quote quote = restTemplate.getForObject("http://gturnquist-quoters.cfapps.io/api/random", Quote.class);` But I need to return a json object). I couldn't figure out how to write the RestTemplate part.

Comment: Just add superset of fields, and make them optional. You can make `status` and `code` required, if you want, but the rest are optional, or rather dependent on status code. You handle the rest in Java code.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Andreas:

- Add the superset of all fields for all possible responses
- Identify the set of fields that are mandatory for every response and make them required
- Make the rest of the fields as optional

Upon receveiving a response, check the status code and implement your logic accordingly.

If you are using Jackson for Deserialization, all fields are optional by default (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551098/how-to-define-optional-json-field-using-jackson))