# Remove Optional from JSON response if is not present

Tags: json, spring-boot

I am building my simple rest server with Spring boot. My problem is the following:

In one of the objects that I have to get through API, there is an Optional field:

```
public class MyObject {
.....

public String description;

public Optional<String> description2;

    public MyObject (Object obj) {

        description = obj.getDescription();

        description2= Optional.ofNullable(obj.getDescription2());
    }
......
}
```

When obj.getDescription2() is null, and retrieve it, in JSON format I got:

```
{

    "description": "Lorem ipsum",
    "description2": {
        "present": false
    }

}
```

What I have to do, to remove description2 from response if it's not present?

Thanks

Comment: why do you need to hold an optional member? why not have a String and annotate it as @Nullable

Comment: because when I create the obj, I can omit description2

Comment: I have the obj in a Map, I don't using a persistence on DB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to define optional json field using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551098/how-to-define-optional-json-field-using-jackson)

Answer (score 0):

you can use  `@JsonValue` and `@JsonCreator` on methods that will output the data as you wish. for example:

```
@JsonValue
public String getDescription2() {
    return desription2.orElse(null);
}
```

Comment: nop... because I have two class, one class is used to save in a HashMap, and another one is used to take and get the request/response API. In this last class I have Optional description2, in the first one not