# Jackson check optional field

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs

## Question

I'm making a POJO (Person) in a JAX-RS project and use Jackson.
I want to create an optional String field (like the country where the person live) and be able to check its length.

### My Tests

By reference to this post ([How to define optional json field using Jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551098/how-to-define-optional-json-field-using-jackson)) I know how to make an optional field. But if I want to check its length with a **`javax.validation.constraints.Pattern`** like follow:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "(?:.{0,12})?")
private final String country;
```

The *country* cannot be NULL or no present anymore.

I tried to add *@Optional* (**`org.jvnet.hk2.annotations.Optional`**) and to specify *country* like `private final Optional<String> country;`. I have not been successful with these 2 methods.

### My actual POJO

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.*;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;

import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

@JsonAutoDetect(creatorVisibility = Visibility.ANY, fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({Person.LAST_NAME, Person.FIRST_NAME, Person.COUNTRY})
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Person {

    /**
     * The format string for the toString method
     */
    private static final String TO_STRING_FORMAT = "%S %s %s";

    /**
     * JSON property name for the last name
     */
    static final String LAST_NAME = "lastName";

    /**
     * JSON property name for the first name
     */
    static final String FIRST_NAME = "firstName";

    /**
     * JSON property name for the country
     */
    static final String COUNTRY = "country";

    /**
     * The last name of the person
     */
    @NotBlank
    private final String lastName;

    /**
     * The first name of the person
     */
    @NotBlank
    private final String firstName;

    /**
     * The country of the person
     */
    @Pattern(regexp = "(?:.{0,12})?")
    private final String country;

    /**
     * Returns an new {@code Person} with its properties initialized from parameters.
     *
     * @param lastName the last name of the person ({@link #lastName})
     * @param firstName the first name of the person ({@link #firstName})
     * @param country the country where the person live ({@link #country})
     */
    // Only used by Jackson for the JSON data deserialization
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    @JsonCreator
    private Person(@JsonProperty(Person.LAST_NAME) String lastName, @JsonProperty(Person.FIRST_NAME) String firstName, @JsonProperty(Person.COUNTRY) String country) {
        this.lastName = lastName.trim();
        this.firstName = firstName.trim();
        this.country = country.trim();
    }

    /**
     * Returns a new {@code Person} with its properties initialized from another one.
     *
     * @param person the instance used to create the new one
     */
    Person(Person person) {
        this.lastName = person.lastName;
        this.firstName = person.firstName;
        this.country = person.country;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a textual representation of the {@code Person}: {@link #lastName} {@link #firstName} {@link #country}.
     * <p>
     * The {@code lastName} is converted to uppercase for better readability of the person's name.
     *
     * @return a string representation of the {@code Person}
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(Person.TO_STRING_FORMAT, this.lastName, this.firstName, this.country);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problem

The problem was that I made a `trim()` on country (a possibly NULL value). See below:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@JsonCreator
private Person(@JsonProperty(Person.LAST_NAME) String lastName, @JsonProperty(Person.FIRST_NAME) String firstName, @JsonProperty(Person.COUNTRY) String country) {
    this.lastName = lastName.trim();
    this.firstName = firstName.trim();
    this.country = country.trim();
}
```

## Solution

I want to thank @TheOddCoder for his solution. My `@Pattern` regex doesn't change but the constructor `private Person(...)` *(@JsonCreator)* changes for the following:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@JsonCreator
private Person(@JsonProperty(Person.LAST_NAME) String lastName, @JsonProperty(Person.FIRST_NAME) String firstName, @JsonProperty(Person.COUNTRY) String country) {
    this.lastName = lastName.trim();
    this.firstName = firstName.trim();
    if(country == null) {
        this.country = country;
    } else {
        this.country = country.trim();
    }
}
```

Comment: _"I want to thank @TheOddCoder for his solution."_ Accept and upvote his answer instead of posting yours then...

Comment: @CassioMazzochiMolin As I mentioned in the commentary on his answer, I had to modify his answer to match it with the source of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would maybe suggest that instead of using an optional for your field, you validate your country if it is set or not and handle it that way.

```
private Person(@JsonProperty(Person.LAST_NAME) String lastName, @JsonProperty(Person.FIRST_NAME) String firstName, @JsonProperty(Person.COUNTRY) String country) {
    this.lastName = lastName.trim();
    this.firstName = firstName.trim();
    if(country == null) { //here you could also use the string empty or null check of apache or guava
        this.country = country;
    } else {
        this.country = country.trim();
    }
}
```

With that you don't have to care if it set or not and the regex would match no matter what.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your useful answer. I just changed the place where your solution is written from the constructor `Person(Person person)` to the constructor `private Person(...)` _(@JsonCreator)_.