# Sparse queries in Jersey

Tags: rest, jersey, jax-rs

In Jersey, is it possible to have a JAX-RS endpoint, where the response payload can be a filtered view of a POJO?

More specifically, suppose we have a pojo Person.

```
public class Person {
     String name;
     Integer age;
     ...
     ...
}
```

We want to be able to return either

```
{

    "name":"nameValue"
}
```

if request is

/persons/23?fields=name

```
enter code here
```

and

```
{

    "age":27
}
```

if request is:

```
/persons/23?fields=age
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19551098/how-to-define-optional-json-field-using-jackson

Comment: You can return a `Response` with any entity.

Comment: https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/entity-filtering.html